# CoreData: realizing faults in the description method by going against Apple's recommendation

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

> Although the description property doesn’t cause a fault to fire, if
>   you implement a custom description that accesses the object’s
>   persistent properties, this does cause a fault to fire. You are
>   strongly discouraged from overriding description in this way.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject)

How would you then make sure that no sensitive information can be printed out/sent to the logging services? The most straight forward way would be to make sure nothing can go through the description unchecked: if you find something that is sensitive, you would redact it there at the source. Any other workaround to make sure nothing can be leaked?

If you would still use the description in a way that is discouraged, you would fire that faults, and get the data (which you need). Are there any side effects aside from the performance hit?

I was reading through a [book](https://books.google.ro/books?id=4g5QDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT54&lpg=PT54&dq=nsmanagedobject%20override%20description&source=bl&ots=75R8kCIYyN&sig=ACfU3U3PbFxMut1VrXC8qhNH9oS-y56EaA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbhaa3t4jpAhVDt3EKHaVVDGgQ6AEwDHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=nsmanagedobject%20override%20description&f=false) section by Marcus Zarra (Core Data in Swift: Data Storage and Management for iOS and OS X) and other sources, and from what I gather this is more like a bad practice/performance hit, rather than any specific problem.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Is any sensitive information printed when the object is a fault?

Comment: @Willeke No, you would get generic information like `MyEntity: 0x777000a3d440> (entity: MyEntity; id: 0xbbb19389cec667f9 <x-coredata://02F64BB5F-TW16-466C-8DA0-BB7839F8AD8F/MyEntity/p`>; data: <fault>)` Even if you have a partial fault (when you have a fetch request and specify the `propertiesToFetch`) it is considered a fault, so you would print the same. (it would not print the fetched data)

Comment: Why do you want to fire a fault if there is no sensitive information in the description?

Comment: Each MyEntity has some sensitive data like SS# and non-sensitive like itemID. I want my logs to contain `SS# <redacted>; itemID: 1234`. If I don't fire the fault, I won't have any of that information, but the general description I mentioned above, which is useless.

Comment: Do you want to override `description` to include more information? This isn't in the question.

Comment: I know from experience that I should not fire faults in `description`. See [Core Data cannot resolve faults when object has “description” attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170679/4244136).

Comment: @Willeke no, no additional information. Only what's already there in the entity. Some of it is sensitive, which cannot be printed, others are not sensitive. If something is sensitive, it should be removed from the log and replaced, whatever is not sensitive can be printed. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: "make sure that no sensitive information can be printed", "I want my logs to contain SS# <redacted>; itemID: 1234" and "no additional information". Do you want to hide sensitive information or do you want to add information to faults? How do the objects end up in the log?